# Location.convert with leading zero

Tags: android, location

I use the following code to convert position to readable format:

```
Location.convert(position, Location.FORMAT_MINUTES);
```

This works well, except for one little thing:

```
51.05074707907328 //input (double)

51°3.04482 //WHAT I GET
51°03.04482 //WHAT I NEED
```

So how do I force that zero? I don't want to manually fix that, but there is nothing about it in [Location reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html).

(If someone is wondering, I do use `.replace(":", "°");` to change : to °)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already do a manual replacement (":" to "°"), you could just as well do the same to add there a zero when there is a single digit between the ":" and ".", for example:

```
.replaceFirst(":(\\d)\\.", ":0$1.")
```

In any case the Location library doesn't give you a lot of power to control these things, so I don't think there is a really clean solution here.

Comment: I guess this will have to do. Thanks